# Wordpress/PHP replace caption tag with div

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have this

`[caption]<img />[/caption]`

I have removed the caption tags usign this

`$content = preg_replace("/\[.*?\]/", "", $content);`

However, I want to replace it with div like this

`<div><img></div>`

What I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please give a realer example. It'll help us to give you correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

you could try like:

```
$search_for = '/\[caption\](.*?)\[\/caption\]/is';
$replace_with = '<div>$1</div>';
$str = "[caption]<img />[/caption]";
$replaced = preg_replace($search_for, $replace_with, $str);
echo $replaced;
```